# How to Make Semi-Transparent Edges Opaque?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

The edges of a mesh show up as semi-transparent when rendered on a transparent background. Using the Set Alpha Node makes the edges opaque but fills them with black. I want the transparent edges filled with the same colors similar to GIMP's Threshold Alpha filter. How can I make those semi-transparent edges fully opaque with the color intact?

[image: Image with transparency over a white background]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a set alpha, connecting the original image's alpha and color, and then add a color ramp onto the alpha.  Then you can adjust the white to whatever level you want to be absolute opaque.  You can change the interpolation to "Constant" as well.[image: Image to set alpha, with alpha passing through color ramp]